# Validation Rule on HTML code within a Rich Text Field

Tags: validation-rule, richtextarea

Creating a Validation Rule similar to `CONTAINS( Procedure__c , 'whatever.com/download')`works on text that is in this field but not on the HTML code.

Is there a way to make this Validation Rule work on the links to images that users might be inserting?

For example: If they are inserting an image using a web address of http://www.whatever.com/download/attachment/image.png and I want to Validate that they are not using this location is there a work around to accomplish this?

Comment: validation works fine for <html><body>
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif" width="42" height="42">
</body></html>

Comment: @IlyaLepesh What did you use? It didn't work for me... I ended up coming up with a trigger that worked, but that seems like overkill if there's an easier way.

Comment: @sfdcfox, I couldn't reproduce the problem. Should I create validation rule declarative? Then try to insert text from my first comment ? If yes, I have validation error.

Comment: @llyaLepesh I am confused.  Did you get a validation rule to work when looking for specific HTML?

Comment: My bad, I was using textarea instead of rich text. Please find some solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that validation is not applicable for Rich Text.

In first place I was thinking about creating hidden field and assign validation to it. Then we could update first field, while we are inserting picture. But it's not supported as well.

From quick fix I could suggest to use process builder:

- choose your object, select when a record is created or edited
- define criteria: conditions are met: field contains restricted url
- immediate action: update field to `Error. URL is invalid`

Process builder validation:

[image]

But if we want to save user experience, we should create Trigger as @sfdcfox has suggested:

```
trigger contactTrigger on Contact (after insert, after update) {
    set<string> restUrls = new set<string>{'www.gravatar.com','blabla'};
        for (contact con :trigger.new) {
            if (!string.isblank(con.picture__c)){
                for (string ur :restUrls) {
                    if(con.picture__c.contains(ur)){
                        con.picture__c.adderror('Trigger: given url isn\'t allowed');
                    }}}}}
```

*Of course restricted urls should be initialized within custom settings or custom object.*

Trigger validation:

[image]

I'm also thinking about creating embedded visualforce page, where with a help of javascript we could check given value. But its not gonna be graceful.